# Infinite loop during window.history.back in Angular JS

Tags: javascript, angularjs, window, directive

I'm building the website and I'm having an issue regarding window.history.back.

I used window.history.back() for 'Back' button, expecting it to function as the back button on browser.

When I get to press 'Back' button twice in a row, I get to infinite loop between two pages.

For example, let's say there are three pages, A, B, and C.

Page B can be accessed only through Page A.

Page C can be accessed only through Page B.

'Back' button is in a bar, implemented as a separate directive. Both Page B and Page C use this directive.

When I get to Page C and press back button, I get directed to Page B. If I click back button again in Page B, I get directed back to Page C. Afterward, I press back button on Page C, I get into infinite loop between Page B and C.

How can I solve this problem?

Code underneath is a directive for bar

```
.directive('BarBack', [function() {
    return {
        replace: false,
        restrict: 'E',
        template: '<bar-button et-icon="keyboard_arrow_left" on-click="ctrl.onClick()">{{ "BACK" | translate }}</bar-button>',
        transclude: false,
        scope: {
            icon: '@',
            stringId: '@',
            state: '@'
        },
        controllerAs: 'ctrl',
        controller: ['$window', function($window) {
            var ctrl = this;

            ctrl.onClick = function() {
                $window.history.back();
            }
        }]
    }
}])
```

I cannot do hard-coded to specific location.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Post your directive code. What is happening is you are not replacing the history.. because technically page c was the last page you were on.

Comment: I added my code. If I need to replace history, what should I replace the history with?

Comment: Based on the code above... I don't see a problem. Do you have a demo of the problem?

Comment: No I don't but can you explain to me about replacing the history?

Comment: I know when I had been using UI router.. when you did a state transition you would specify a replace parameter and it essentially removed the previous history marker from history. E.g: going to a create screen (a screen which you don't want the user to be able to go back to). But in your case the $window.history.back() should work correctly (I have tested) so it must be a problem somewhere else in the code. Another option would be to handle the push state yourself (i doubt you want to). Its hard to tell without seeing other pieces of code. Sorry.